# How to verify go.sum module hashes from Bash?

Tags: go-modules

Mostly from intellectual curiosity, I'd like to verify `go.sum` hashes to better understand how the process works. But I'm unable to verify the hashes. What am I doing wrong?

Using [Trillian v1.3.0](https://github.com/google/trillian/releases/tag/v1.3.0)

```sh
MOD=github.com/google/trillian
REL=v1.3.0
```

and

```sh
curl --silent https://sum.golang.org/lookup/${MOD}@${REL}
55144
github.com/google/trillian v1.3.0 h1:Mr/GnBzXQvowTJVaWPox/mMcYf2L1hJKNBAOffNBLlE=
github.com/google/trillian v1.3.0/go.mod h1:qYuTstG3eXZCOnvIfE8IeoEQDrjpm1dkfydVTBiSyx8=

go.sum database tree
156802
lFayLBRYOtnUSyDaIvmpVKydST+NdNWNkfSVehq3Ty8=

— sum.golang.org Az3grsd5k3D+TW56dDtJTGqaF+x6L16iYOWvSoO/T/M/UGpCGaJgDfGKvco2qJuo1Hk/j0RUxpndYL68xfrGiWacAAk=
```

**Aside**: is there a way to have the API return JSON? Parameters are disallowed.

IIUC `Mr/GnBzXQvowTJVaWPox/mMcYf2L1hJKNBAOffNBLlE=` should be result of zipping the module's directory, hashing and then base64 encoding it, but it isn't:

```sh
zip -r - "${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/${MOD}@${REL}" | \
sha256sum | \
head --bytes=64 | \
base64 --wrap=0
MzQxNjhkNTQzZTk0MjFjY2FjN2NjYTljMzczZDgwYmE0MzE1ZjY4YzY3OWYzNzZjNTc4OTFiMTRlNzA0NjAwMQ==
```

If I work backwards from the hash, it appears to be binary encoded. So, I tried `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary` but that doesn't get me the correct hash either:

```sh
zip -r - "${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/${MOD}@${REL}" | \
openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
base64
NBaNVD6UIcysfMqcNz2AukMV9oxnnzdsV4kbFOcEYAE=
```

Answer (score 4):

Golang modules checksum has special logic to calc Hash based on SHA256, finally encoded to Base64.

It is hard to verify `go.sum` only using Bash scripts.

Take a look at: https://github.com/vikyd/go-checksum